# Is $a^p/p+b^q/q \ge ab$ true of any rational $p$, $q$ greater than $2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic

From Beckingbach & Bellman, Introduction to Inequalities, p.61,
they prove that

(1)  $a^p/p+b^q/q \ge ab$

where $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers and $p$ and $q$ are rational numbers, and

$1/p+1/q=1$ .

Can equation (1) be proven or disproven for the case of all rational $p$ and $q$ without the further condition, and $p>2$, $q>2$?

Comment: With $a,b$ constrained to be non-negative integers, higher exponents help left side the least when $a=b=1$. What do you get in that case? Does that hold, when $p>2,q>2$?

Comment: You're right. We have to add the condition a>1, b>1.  Then what?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't hold for p=q=1 obviously for a=b=3.

Comment: Obviously.  I was really interested in the case $p>2$, $q>2$

Comment: Let a=b=1, we have $\frac1p+\frac1q\ge 1$,  $p\gt 2,q\gt 2$ doesn't meet the condition

Comment: You're right.  It looks like we have to add the condition a>1, b>1.  Then, the question remains?